# Find the continuous function

Tags: functions, continuity

**Problem**

> Let the following conditions be satisfied:
>
> $$\text{(i)} \hspace{1 mm} f = f(x) \hspace{1 mm} \text{and} \hspace{1 mm} g = g(x) \hspace{1 mm} \text{are continuous functions on [0,1],}$$  $$\hspace{9 mm}\text{(ii)} \hspace{1 mm} \text{there exists a number} \hspace{1 mm} a \hspace{1 mm}\text{such that} \hspace{1 mm} 0 < f(x) \leq a < 1 \hspace{1 mm} \text{on} \hspace{1 mm} [0,1], $$ $$\hspace{5 mm}\text{(iii)} \hspace{1 mm} \text{there exists a number} \hspace{1 mm} u \hspace{1 mm} \text{such that} \hspace{1 mm} \max_{0 \leq x\leq 1}(g(x)+uf(x)) = u.$$ Find constants $A $ and $B$ such that $F(x) = \dfrac{Ag(x)}{f(x)+B}$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$ satisfying $\displaystyle \max_{0 \leq x \leq 1} F(x) = u$, and prove that your function has the required properties.

How do I utilize the information they have given me about the maximums and minimums and also the value of $a$ to solve the problem?

Comment: Some experimenting & guessing is required. Part (iii) shows that $g(x) + uf(x) \le u$ for all $x$. Try factoring $u$ to one side of this inequality, that should suggest something.

Comment: We have $g(x) \leq u(1-f(x))$. So we could say $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) \leq u(1-x)$? I just need to come up with a $g(x)$ now?

Comment: No. Take the first expression in your comment and divide across by $(1-f(x))$, and then find the appropriate $A,B$. You cannot choose $f,g$, they are given. All you can use is the given properties.

Comment: $u \geq \dfrac{g(x)}{1-f(x)}$. Then we have that $A = -1$ and $B = -1$?

Comment: Bingo. Also, your answer should just confirm that the $\max$ of the resulting function is $u$ (that is, the value of $u$ is attained for some suitable $x$).

Comment: Right, so what was the purpose of condition (ii) then?

Comment: To ensure that the denominator is never zero. (Otherwise you could not be sure that dividing by $1-f(x)$ is valid.)

Comment: There are other $A$ and $B$ that satisfy this too right?

Comment: That is not clear to me...

Comment: We have $\dfrac{g(x)}{f(x)-1}$ right? we can keep making $|A|$ and $|B|$ larger.

Comment: I don't see how you can do that.

Comment: We then have $\dfrac{2g(x)}{f(x)-2}$. Doesn't that work?

Comment: How do you show that the $\max$ is $u$?

Comment: Oh, good point. Sorry I get it now.